# How to parse XML in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I have the following SQL Server query and I have to convert it into Oracle:

```
Select PhotoNumber, cast(cast(cast( PhotoInfo as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)) as XML).value('(/DataIM/PhotoChosen/Photo/jpg)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as PhotoInfo 
From ProfilePictures 
Where photosourcetype = 10
```

I converted it to Oracle like the following

```
Select PhotoNumber, extract(xmltype(photoinfo,1), '(/DataIM/PhotoChosen/Photo/jpg)[1]') "photoinfo"
    From ProfilePictures 
    Where photosourcetype = 10
```

It gives me error as invalid token in /DataIM/PhotoChosen/Photo/jpg)[1]

How do I parse my XML? I just want the details in string.

Comment: Ha, that's kind of answered my comment on your previous question... but (a) `extract()` is deprecated, and (b) why do you have the `)` in the XPath? Looks like you left that in when you removed the matching `(` from the SQL Server version? Including a sample XML document might help if that isn't the only issue.

Comment: @AlexPoole that ) was a typo, i actually just want to know how can i convert a blob i to xml and then parse it to get my desired information. I used extract because thats what i found on google..lol...

Comment: Won't be able to post xml due to some policies.  Perhaps you can explain me using a samle xml if that is possible.

Comment: It's really up to you to provide a sample with the correct structure - it doesn't have to have real data. What's you've posted now with the mismatched parentheses corrected works, or at least doesn't throw that error - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7b3ea8e19dee4b5d073fd3fbe0c9f6e6).

Comment: @AlexPoole no, after fixing the mismatched parenthesis, it doesn't work. Can you tell me if i am following the right syntax to convert a blob into xml and then convert that thing into string ? Is my oracle syntax correct ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've shown, with balanced parentheses, works:

```
Select PhotoNumber, extract(xmltype(photoinfo,1), '(/DataIM/PhotoChosen/Photo/jpg)[1]') "photoinfo"
    From ProfilePictures 
    Where photosourcetype = 10
```

```
PHOTONUMBER | photoinfo              
----------- | -----------------------
         42 | <jpg>my_photo.jpg</jpg>
```

though I'm not sure what the parentheses are doing, it works without too. You probably only want the actual string, not the `jpg` node and its contents; so you can add `/text()` to the XPath to get that.

But `extract` is deprecated, so it would be better to use XMLQuery:

```
Select PhotoNumber,
        XMLQuery(
            '/DataIM/PhotoChosen/Photo/jpg[1]/text()'
            passing xmltype(photoinfo, 1)
            returning content
        ).getstringval() "photoinfo"
    From ProfilePictures 
    Where photosourcetype = 10
```

```
PHOTONUMBER | photoinfo   
----------- | ------------
         42 | my_photo.jpg
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=72c52d921eae7b57074ad25d16944d9d)

I've kept your [quoted identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA), but I'd suggest you avoid those unless really necessary.

You are converting the BLOB to XML using character set identifier 1. Hopefully that is correct and what you want. You can see which charcacter set that actually is with:

```
select nls_charset_name(1) from dual;
```

which is reported as US7ASCII on my system, and I suspect everywhere as that's the old default.

Passing 0 instead uses the database character set. You need to know what character set the BLOB data uses though. If you know that you can look up the correct number to use with, for example:

```
select nls_charset_id('UTF8') from dual;
```

or pass it in directly in the `xmltype()` call:

```
...
            passing xmltype(photoinfo, nls_charset_id('UTF8'))
...
```